`belongs_to` and `before_create` order in Rails
Given a scenario where a book belongs to an author:
class Book < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :author
end

Now let's add a before_create :ensure_something to the book model. The ensure_something method needs to verify something, but we need to access the author for this verification. Inside the ensure_something method, can we be sure that the variable author exists, i.e. is not nil?

I've checked the belongs_to docs and the callback order (see also here). However, I don't see how the assocation belongs_to and the callbacks relate to each other in terms of ordering.
My expectation is that once we are in ensure_something the variable author is guaranteed to exist, but I'm not 100% sure based on the docs and would like to check this.
I know that we can pass optional to belongs_to and it states:

When set to true, the association will not have its presence validated.

As optional is by default set to false, I read this as "the association will have its presence validated by default". The question is if this actually happens before the before_create callback is called.

In Rails, belongs_to (with optional: false, the default) ensures author_id
is present before saving/creating Book.
During before_create, author_id is validated (not nil), but author may
not be loaded yet.
To access author in before_create (e.g., in ensure_something), explicitly
call self.author. Rails will load it if not already loaded.
If optional: true, author_id can be nil.
Conclusion:

author_id is guaranteed if optional: false.
Use self.author to access the loaded author.


@uberdave Thanks a lot for your comment. If you post this as answer with links to the docs/code/... corroborating your statements, I'd certainly mark this as accepted answer.

The idea that you need to explicitly call the method on self is nonsense. When you call author it's implicitly called on self unless you're doing something really silly like shadowing it with a local variable. While there is nothing wrong with calling it with an explicit recipient it's less idiomatic.

The validation added by belongs_to is just a plain old presence validation and behaves just like any other validation.
if required
  if ActiveRecord.belongs_to_required_validates_foreign_key
    model.validates_presence_of reflection.name, message: :required

The order of callbacks for creating a record is:

before_validation
after_validation
before_save
around_save
before_create
around_create
after_create
after_save
after_commit

As you can see the validations happen at the very top of the chain.

My expectation is that once we are in ensure_something the variable author is guaranteed to exist, but I'm not 100% sure based on the docs and would like to check this.

author is not a variable. It's a method which is generated by the belongs_to macro.
The validation should ensure that the subsequent callback doesn't fire if the validations fail but there are ways to suppress or bypass validations. It is also possible (but very unlikely) that a race condition could occur where the associated record is deleted after the validation is performed but before the record is saved. If author is a new record the validation could pass even if the author is not successfully saved later.
So in other words the validation gives you a reasonable degree of certainty but the only thing that's actually certain in life is death and taxes.

In Rails, the belongs_to association by default requires the associated object (in this case, author) to be present, unless you explicitly specify optional: true. Therefore, Rails will validate the presence of the author before a record is created, ensuring that an associated author_id is present unless the belongs_to association is marked as optional.
To answer your specific question: whether or not the author is guaranteed to be present during the before_create callback depends on a couple of factors:
Callback Order: The before_create callback is triggered before the record is persisted to the database. However, the actual presence validation (checking if the author_id is present) happens at the validation stage, which occurs before before_create. This means that, if the record passes the validation, you can expect the author to exist and be accessible in the before_create callback, provided that optional: true is not set.
belongs_to Validation: By default, the belongs_to association adds a validation for the presence of the associated object (in this case, the author). Therefore, unless the belongs_to :author is marked as optional: true, the author must be present for the record to be valid, and the validation will prevent saving the record if the author is nil.
Example:
class Book < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :author
  before_create :ensure_something
  private
  def ensure_something
    raise "Author is missing" if author.nil?        
    # Other logic for ensure_something
  end
end

In the above scenario, since optional: true is not used, the presence of author is validated before before_create, so you can safely assume that author is not nil inside the ensure_something method.
